# Poster---sciposter----How to automatically adjust Line spacing to full span poster column height?

Tags: posters, sciposter

Situation:
I have a latex poster (sciposter) with paper size a0. I have 3 columns. However, because the first has less content compared to the others. The other columns content shrink so that heights of all 3 columns are the same. The problem is, the height of content is only about 3/4 of the height of a0 size paper, therefore leading to a significant amount of white space in the bottom of the a0 size poster. The contents of the 2nd and 3rd column seem also to densely pack together.

Wish:
I cannot move stuff from the 2nd or 3rd columns to the first column. I hope to have a command that can automatically adjust the line spacing of the contents of all columns so that the contents can span the whole height of the a0 size paper or at least 9/10 of the height of the a0 size paper.

Comment: This is your 11th question and 9 of your questions have answers to it -- you accepted **not** a single one! **This is not how TeX.SX works!** You should show your appreciation of the users' will to help you. (No, I am not one of the users who answered a question from you)

Comment: You can adjust \baselinskip manually, To compute the value automatically you would need to know how how many lines of text are used.